# Deploy NodeJS Express on amplify

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-amplify

I am trying to deploy an app on AWS Amplify.
The app is React front and and NodeJS Express backend.
The frontend works fine, but the backend is just stuck without any reasonable explanation

My YML file is

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build-backend
    postBuild:
        commands:
        - cd ..
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build-frontend
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: ./client/build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

build backend-script :

```
"build-backend": "cd server && npm run start",
```

npm run start script:

```
"start": "npm install && node index.js"
```

The build is getting stuck on the npm install and after 10-20 minutes just "gives up" without the following log

```
2021-04-22T11:49:20.693Z [INFO]: > server@1.0.0 start /codebuild/output/src650104622/src/myBlog/server
                                 > npm install && node index.js
2021-04-22T11:49:26.976Z [INFO]: > bcrypt@5.0.0 install /codebuild/output/src650104622/src/myBlog/server/node_modules/bcrypt
                                 > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

Thanks

Comment: ever got a solution to your question?

Comment: @BioAbnerJ no. Found out that it is wasn't the right call. Amplify is its own BE framework, so deploying NodeJS on it is not right, though I still think it is possible somehow.

Comment: Is there any way at all to deploy a nodejs app to AWS?

Comment: @BioAbnerJ You can use fargate service: https://medium.com/@arliber/aws-fargate-from-start-to-finish-for-a-nodejs-app-9a0e5fbf6361

Answer (score 4):

I came across this thread while looking for a solution for my project. And because there are no more answers here, I'll tell you what I could find myself.

Amplify works fine with **SSG web** applications (Gatsby, etc.), with **SSR** (React, NextJS, NuxtJS, etc.) and with **simple NodeJS and ExpressJS** applications (which only run on requests because Amplify uses Lambda-functions to handle it). So:

- If you need a **simple ExpressJS application for your API** you can
  use the following serverless Ampl solution:
  https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-rest/express-server/q/platform/js/
- If you need **a socket.io application** (or another **constantly
  running** application) you need to use **[AWS Fargate](https://medium.com/@arliber/aws-fargate-from-start-to-finish-for-a-nodejs-app-9a0e5fbf6361)** (uses
  docker images) or **[AWS EC2](https://aws.plainenglish.io/deploying-a-nodejs-application-in-aws-ec2-c1618b9b3874)** (works on simple virtual machine
  with access by SSH) solutions.

**P.S.** If you have any other information on this subject, please post it here.